# Matching a duplicate entries in two columns and for those that have count >1 taking a third value for both and adding them

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table containing: ID, FEATURE_NAME (that would be a name of the city), STATE_ALPHA (two letter country identifier like 'AL' for Alabama), and POPULATION_DATA.

I need to:

1. find entries that have same FEATURE_NAME and STATE_ALPHA
2. take values for POPULATION_DATA in both(or more) appearances and add them
3. write down the sum in POPULATION_DATA where all addends are from.

Example:

```
- ID !FEATURE NAME !  STATE_ALPHA  !  POPULATION DATA
-  1   Woodland          WA             83 
-  2   Woodland          WA            5426
-  3   Vining            KS             354 
-  4   Vining            KS             276
-  5   Vining            KS            1450
```

What I need to get is:

```
- ID !FEATURE NAME !  STATE_ALPHA  !  POPULATION DATA
-  1   Woodland          WA            5509
-  2   Woodland          WA            5509
-  3   Vining            KS            2080 
-  4   Vining            KS            2080
-  5   Vining            KS            2080
```

I googled for hours and dont even know where to start. Also I'll run that script on a view not on original table, I don't know does it changes anything. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with an aggregation and a join:

```
select t.id, t.feature_name, t.state_alpha, sumpop as Population_Data
from t join
     (select feature_name, state_alpha, sum(population_data) as sumpop
      from t
      group by feature_name, state_alpha
     ) fs
     on t.feature_name = fs.feature_name and
        t.state_alpha = fs.state_alpha;
```

The aggregation sums the population (in the subquery `fs`).  This result is joined back to the original data.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, a simple query should work where the table name is `tablename`

```
SELECT ID, FEATURE_NAME, STATE_ALPHA, POPULATION_DATA FROM tablename
FROM tablename
GROUP BY FEATURE_NAME, STATE_ALPHA
```

Comment: . . This answer is not correct.  It will return only one `id` per feature/state combination, but the OP is looking for all such combinations.